# Glassfish5 not starting

Tags: server, glassfish, glassfish-5

i have tomcat working fine, the error is not even about the port, which i know how to change, is this some sort of java version compatibility problem?

i'm a student so i don't know much

here's the output

```
$ asadmin start-domain domain1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

the command $ asadmin list-applications says the server is not up

i'm on Mx Linux fully updated

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

i haven't done anything yet, i can't find any problem similar to this on google

Answer (score 0):

It was the JDK version

Inside netbeans when i clicked on Start to start the server, it says something about JDK 11, netbeans has a feature that let's you download many open JDK versions, i downloaded a random openJDK8 version and it worked

I don't know how to edit the JDK version manually or from any other IDE though, but my (video) class is using netbeans so for now i'm ok (they didn't teach on video because the video is 2 years old so it's outdated)